# How to solve 404 error in flume while streaming data from twitter?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to stream some data from Twitter API using flume. The code did work initially. but now I am getting 404 error:

```
INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: 404: The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.

Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api
```

below is my conf file code.

```
TwitterAgent.sources= Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels= MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks=HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels=MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey=<code>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret=    <code>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken=<code>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret= <code>

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords= hadoop, bigdata

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/tweets
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=600
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100
```

Comment: Generally speaking, the problem exists internally to the cloudera code. Or Twitter disabled your API key (click the link, it doesn't exist)

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was the time synchronization error between my local storage and hdfs.

Comment: Right, the CDH VM doesn't sync time to well. Feel free to add your solution below

Comment: I just synchronized the time of VMware and my windows system manually and the problem got solved.

Comment: Again, you can put that as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just synchronized the time of VMware and my windows system manually and the problem got solved.